# Logging of method calls for recreation

Tags: unity

Some games have the option to let you play offline and sync with a server once you have internet again. To prevent cheating and validate if it was an authentic play, usually some sort of log of all input actions is sent and validated afterwards on the server.

In my case I would be interested in a single MonoBehaviour and having all its method calls logged with the its parameters values. Giving this input, the game result output should be the same. (There is no random involved and no physics interaction)

- One way would be just a writer at the start of each method that logs the timestamp, method name and paramter
- Another would be maybe something like a multi delegate inbetween that calls both my method and a writer class

Is there something build-in in Unity that does this already like an annotation for the methods I want to track or something like an audit interface?

Comment: It sounds like you have three workable approaches here. Which one is best for your project's needs and your team's style of working is a question that you are much better-positioned to answer than Interned randos like us who know only a paragraph or two about your situation. Which approach appeals to you? Do you see a specific problem with it that we can help you overcome?

Comment: I have two approaches here and would like to know if there is a third one that I might have missed that to not reinvent the wheel. I will rephrase the question accordingly

Comment: "Is there another way" usually has the uninteresting answer "yes, lots (but many of them are silly/bad)". "Is there a *better* way" is more interesting, but relies on which evaluation criteria you use to define "better". What I'd recommend doing is identifying a specific problem with the two approaches you've thought of that's making you reluctant to jump into either one, and ask for a solution to that problem. It might not even require a third way, maybe just an implementation detail of the two you've already considered.